# laravel Route get function

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-routing

i'm new to laravel Framework, i have a basic knowlege in php oop,
in the web.php inside the routes folder this code

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    echo 'Hello!';
});
```

As far as i know that :: operator is used with static functions so i tried to find the find the static function "get" but i didn't found it.

Comment: FYI  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades#facade-class-reference  if you need to know what class a facade is the static proxy for.

Answer (score 7):

Because the Laravel architecture is a little bit more complex than just using static classes. This is what we call Facades.

When you call Route::get(), the Route class will try to get the instance of the real route object and then call the get() method.

The class is this one:

```
/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php
```

And the method:

```
/**
 * Register a new GET route with the router.
 *
 * @param  string  $uri
 * @param  \Closure|array|string|null  $action
 * @return \Illuminate\Routing\Route
 */
public function get($uri, $action = null)
{
    return $this->addRoute(['GET', 'HEAD'], $uri, $action);
}
```

To better understand Facades, please read:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades

https://www.sitepoint.com/how-laravel-facades-work-and-how-to-use-them-elsewhere/

The ServiceContainer is a another big player in this process, read about it too:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/container

Comment: i didn't find those lines in the file!

Comment: Because of its complexity. Have you looked into the Route ancestor? Have you understood how getFacadeAccessor work? It's all done via the IoC Container, so I pasted some links for you to understand it better.

Comment: another question please, how can i user Router in Router::get however i'm not using any namespace to target it!

Comment: Look at `config/app.php` and you should find `'Route' => Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route::class,`, this is another Laravel "black magic" it requires those classes automatically for you, so if your are not using a namespace, they should work out of the box. If you are on a namespaced class, you have to required them from root, by doing ´use Route´  on the top of your class.

Answer (score 1):

`Route` is a [facade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/facades) to non-static functions. Here's the `Route::get()` function: https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Routing/Router.html#method_get

Comment: public function __construct($methods, $uri, $action)
    {
        $this->uri = $uri;
        $this->methods = (array) $methods;
        $this->action = $this->parseAction($action);

        if (in_array('GET', $this->methods) && ! in_array('HEAD', $this->methods)) {
            $this->methods[] = 'HEAD';
        }

        if (isset($this->action['prefix'])) {
            $this->prefix($this->action['prefix']);
        }
    }

Comment: @SeifEddineSlimene OK? What's that supposed to mean?